# C# How to Use button click Function from code and not only users click

Tags: c#, button

Lets assume I have this code

```
 private void Exitbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

And I want to call this function from another part of my code and not only from the click of the user

```
code...
{
    ...do something...
    Exitbtn_Click()
}
```

I have tried `Exitbtn.Click +=new EventHandler(Exitbtn_Click);` but it doesn't work i believe it is because of the word new but I am not sure, I am new to C#

Comment: `Exitbtn_Click(null, EventArgs.Empty);` ?

Comment: Why not just call `Application.Exit()` rather than `Exitbtn_Click`?

Comment: @john can you explain that ?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay It is not for an exit button i just wanted to make my example easier to understand what i want

Comment: `Exitbtn.PerformClick();` ?!?!?

Answer (score 2):

Whilst you could call:

```
Exitbtn_Click(null, EventArgs.Empty);
```

If you actually need `sender` / `EventArgs` to be populated it could become messy.

Personally it seems cleaner to wrap the common logic in a private method and call from both places.

```
private void ApplicationExit()
{
    Application.Exit();
}

private void Exitbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationExit();
}

code...
{
    ...do something...
    ApplicationExit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As john said in the comments:

```
  Exitbtn_Click(null, EventArgs.Empty);
```